# How to block pingdom bots in nginx?

Tags: nginx, bots, pingdom

Considering that Pingdom is a high reputable site, I tried to subscribe for their uptime monitoring service. However, even though I setup for 5 minutes interval, their bot **Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4** keeps accessing my site not once every second, but tens of times every second! Resulting thousands of access per minute!

Then I tried to completely cancel the service but still get bombarded by their bot. I tried to block in robots.txt, but apparently they chokes it on. Next, I tried to block in nginx.conf with this command:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* Pingdom.com_bot) {
        return 403;
}
```

It works, but I see a lot of 503 errors in access.log. How to not log this bot? Really really annoying. I regret ever subscribed to their service.

Comment: Given the high reputation of their site, I doubt this is on purpose. Why don't you contact their support? FWIW, I use Pingdom on my site and see it obey to the interval I specify.

Comment: Thanks, but so far I haven't got any reply from them.

Comment: @user1801605 If you managed to solved can you post your answer here ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post [about blocking w00tw00t](http://myatus.com/p/blocking-w00tw00t-scans/) which you could easily adopt.

The easiest option for you to adapt would proablably beeing the fail2ban one.

using a fail regex triggering on your 403 error.

So something like

```
[Definition]
failregex =  ^<HOST> .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 403 [0-9]{1,} ".+" ".+"$
ignoreregex=
```

in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-pindotban.conf

and

```
[pingdotban]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = nginx-pingdotban
logpath = /path/to/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 5
bantime = 360000
```

in /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

You can test the regex with

```
fail2ban-regex logfile /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nging-pingdotban.conf
```

Also the iptable variant could be adopted with something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "the useragent" -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's little bit complicated. I end up using nginx command to block the bot.